# Fit background image in Control SWT

Tags: java, image, swt, draw, jface

I am trying to set a background image for a ListViewer.

```
    listViewer = new ListViewer(parent);
    listViewer.setContentProvider(this);
    listViewer.setLabelProvider(this);
    listViewer.getList().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,true,true));
    Image image = new Image(Display.getDefault(), ListPart.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/blurred.jpg"));
    Rectangle imageBounds = image.getBounds();
    Rectangle rectangle = listViewer.getList().getBounds();

    GC gc = new GC(listViewer.getList());
    gc.drawImage(image, imageBounds.x, imageBounds.y,imageBounds.width,imageBounds.height,rectangle.x,rectangle.y,rectangle.width,rectangle.height);
    listViewer.getList().setBackgroundImage(image);
```

I tried to draw the image with GC but it doesn't work. If I leave the image as it is, it doesn't stretch after the List.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to register a `PaintListener` at the List and draw the image within the listeners `paint` method?

Comment: Yes, and it drew the image over the content of my List.

Comment: In SWT, controls other than `Canvas` aren't really meant for custom drawing, but for some it works. Apparently, `List` on your platform isn't among them. A workaround could be to register a resize listener that sets the background image whenever the size of the list is changed. However, that might flicker.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann , unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I added a resize listener for the List as you said, and the output is the same, the image doesn't fit the List.

Comment: I think you need to scale the image to the client area of the list. See here for how to scale images in SWT: https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html#Scaling